# Challenge: MySQL users table default settings

Tags: mysql, default

## UPDATE:

I have since realized that the way I was doing this was suboptimal and could never have worked properly, and am now using two tables instead of three, which seems to work.

You're welcome to answer if you have the solution, but only to help others if they have a similar problem.

---

I have a users table with uid, name and basic info. I have a settings table with sid, the name of the setting and the default value of the setting.

I also have a users_settings table with sid, uid and value, linking users' settings to both the settings' names and the users' names.

In one query, how would I select a user, and "loop" through the settings table, selecting either the user's setting in users_settings if it exists, or that setting's default value if not, for each setting?

Preferably each setting would appear in the result set as a column (the column's name being the setting's name and the value being the setting's value).

In case that was unintelligible, here's an example:

users table:

```
uid name   email
1   Maria  maria@example.com
4   George george@example.com
```

settings table:

```
sid name     default_value
1   uicolour #f00
2   language en
```

users_settings table:

```
uid sid value
4   1   #000
1   2   es
```

Desired result from MySQL query for uid 4:

```
uid name   email              setting_colour setting_language
4   George george@example.com #000           en
```

Desired result from MySQL query for uid 1:

```
uid name   email             setting_colour setting_language
1   Maria  maria@example.com #f00           es
```

Comment: Well I've tried LEFT and INNER JOINs, but all I can get is the setting if it exists. I can't think of any way to incorporate the default setting into the result. I need some sort of loop and test within the query, I think.

I suppose I could just make the signup form put values in and deprecate default_value. It would duplicate a lot of data though.

Comment: I meant, can you add the query(s) that you tried into your answer, you may be close and just need a tweak.

Comment: The only code I've tried is with the setting's name in the setting's table so it wouldn't be close. I haven't done any double-left-joins between the settings, user_settings and users table. I can assure you that I have no idea how to go about this :P

Comment: That's not good database design. If you add more settings, then you have to add more columns to your users table.

Comment: See my answer below - note, this works with your original schema which is a better design.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after ganking around with it, and learning more about left joins, this appears to work:

```
SELECT t_users.*, t_users_settings.*, t_settings.*
FROM t_users 
LEFT JOIN t_users_settings ON t_users.uid = t_users_settings.t_uid  
LEFT JOIN t_settings ON t_settings.t_sid != t_users_settings.t_sid
WHERE t_users_settings.t_sid IS NOT NULL 
AND t_users_settings.t_uid IS NOT NULL 
AND t_users.uid = '<input user id here>';
```

Comment: Although, if you add more settings to the settings table you end up with more records. I don't know a better way to structure the query than to add more joins, but that is better than adding more columns in the database. If anyone has a better query, I would appreciate the correction as this was a learning thing for me as well.

Comment: it does seem to me that the system wasn't designed for this. If it's this hard / hacky then there is probably a better way to structure the data.

Comment: I think the data structure is good, you've got a table of default settings, custom settings and users. It's setup in a way you can add more defaults without restructuring the tables. I'm just not good enough with sql yet to know how to structure the query to get all results in one set. I think I'll post this query (since it works) over on code review and see what they say.

Comment: Oh, I might also consider changing your column names. NAME and VALUE are reserved words in mysql.

Comment: Not according to this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-0.html

Comment: Huh. Good point. They get highlighted as reserved in mysql workbench, I just assumed. Oops. :/